# Codeigniter :- get monthy recap report

Tags: php, mysql, string, codeigniter

I'm trying to get report by month by counting number of rows by filtering create_date as below:

```
for ($i= 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {

    if ($i >= 1 && $i <= 9) { 
        $month = '0' . $i;
    } 
    else {
        $month = $i;
    }

    $month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today - '  . $i . 'month'));  
    var_dump($month);  

    $where = array('created_date >=' => $month . " 00:00:00", 'created_time <=' => $month . " 23:59:59");
    $get_opportunities_list[$month] = count($this->db->where($where)->get('tbl_project')->result());
```

When I `var_dump($month);` I  get the exact date and the month but the year showing 2015 instead 2016. Please help..

```
Var_dump: string(10) "2016-10-22" string(10) "2016-09-22" string(10) "2016-08-22" string(10) "2016-07-22" string(10) "2016-06-22" string(10) "2016-05-22" string(10) "2016-04-22" string(10) "2016-03-22" string(10) "2016-02-22" string(10) "2016-01-22" string(10) "2015-12-22" string(10) "2015-11-22"
```

Comment: Not making sense, you say you gt the right date but for last year and yet you show the var dump as this years date?  And the code you supplied shows the months for this year

Comment: What are you doing man? Why not just `order by created_date` ?

Comment: @Blinkydamo If you scroll in the var dump you'll see the last two strings show the date 2015. Unsure if this is relevant.

Comment: You have started in the tenth month of 2015 and gone back 12 months.  Simple maths 10 - 12 = -2.  October back 10 months = jan 2016, -2 = nov 2015. If you only what to go back to jan of the given year then check the year with an if on each loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
$month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y').'-'.$i.'-'.date('d')));
```

in place of

```
$month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today - '  . $i . 'month'));
```

You are not defining year in `strtotime()`, so by default it is assuming date from past.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using php Datetime classes to this type of operations.

```
$begin = new DateTime('2016-01-01');
$end = new DateTime();
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
foreach ($daterange as $date) {
    $where = [
        'created_date >=' => $date->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'),
        'created_time <=' => $date->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59')
    ];
    $get_opportunities_list[$date->format('Y-m-d')] = count($this->db->where($where)->get('tbl_project')->result());
}
```

Also I recommend you to avoid querying the database within a loop.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/682943)**

```
for ($i= 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    if ( $i <= 9)  { 
    $month = '0' . $i;
    } else {
    $month = $i; 
    }
    $date = date("d");
    $year = date("Y");
    $month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date."-" . $i ."-". $year));  
    var_dump( $month );  
}
```